# Subviews gets trimmed when out of UITableViewCell bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been looking around and can't find a solution to my problem. I have a `UIImageView` as subview of `UITableViewCell`, I add it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the frame of subview starts on cell-1 and goes out of cell-1, getting into cell-2.

Basically, I want my image to be on the middle of two cells. Now, when `tableView`first loads, it appears correctly, but when I scroll the cells down and go back, the image is trimmed, showing only the part that is in cell-1 bounds.

I know iOS 7 has a `scrollView` between `contentView` and `cell`. When I log on my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (cell.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds == YES || cell.contentView.clipsToBounds == YES || cell.clipsToBounds == YES) {
    NSLog(@"CLIP = YES");
} else {
    NSLog(@"CLIP = NO");
}
```

it shows me that `cell`, `contentView` and `scrollView` have the property `clipToBounds` set to `NO`, which is what I want.

I just don't know why `subviews` still get trimmed.

Comment: The actual hierarchy is more complex than you think. In the debugger, send `recursiveDescription` to one of your cells, and you'd understand.

Comment: I gave you one. Did you inspect the view hierarchy yet?

Comment: No, I don't even know how to do that.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in a place where you can access your table view or one of your cells. When the program pauses there, get a reference to the cell by printing it or its pointer (`po cell` or `p cell`). Continue execution. When the problem occurs, pause execution, and send `recursiveDescription` to the cell you got the reference of (`po [(UITableViewCell *)0x123456789) recursiveDescription]`.

Comment: Thanks. It appears to be a `UITableViewCellSeparatorView` over there as well. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I don't really know. I just pointed you to a good place to start sorting out the issue. Suggest going through the views and seeing which one has `clipsToBounds` set.

Comment: Ok, as I suspected, every view on the hierarchy has the property `clipToBounds` set to `NO`.

Comment: Upload your project and I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same problem as you.

I realised that the problem was my cell had non-transparent backgrounds. The subviews weren't being clipped, they were simply getting covered by the background colours of previously added cells.

You can't control the order in which cells get added to the table view, so you'd have to use [`UIColor clearColor]` as the background colour of your cells to get the desired effect.

If that's an issue, set the `zPosition` of your subview to a high enough number and you'd hopefully be good to go.